# skip hidden files and directories in pathlib glob

Tags: python, pathlib

With

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("/my/path")
for p in path.rglob("*"):
    print(p)
```

I can get all files and directories in `/my/path`. How can I skip hidden files and directories?

From

```
file
.hidden_file
dir /
   file
   .hidden_file
.hidden_dir / 
   file
   .hidden_file
```

I just want to get

```
file
dir /
   file
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:
`path.rglob('*')`

Try this:
`path.rglob('[!.]*') if not os.path.isdir(p)`

Unfortunately I can't test now, but hopefully it'll do.

Comment: That doesn't exclude files in hidden directories, e.g., `.hidden/myfile.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no builtin way to do this, and `glob` definitely in not suitable for it. You can build it on top of `os.walk` I guess: filter the `files` array at each step, as well as modify `dirs` in-place to avoid recursing into hidden directories.

Do note that the Unix conception of hidden files (the dotfile hack) isn't necessarily sufficient (or compatible, kind-of) for other OS e.g. macOS does use dotfiles but also has a stat flag (`UF_HIDDEN`), and Windows *should* only use the relevant stat flag (`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`) though ignoring dotfiles probably doesn't help.

Ideally there'd be a filewalker which would do that automatically, including support for ignorefiles (similar to Rust's [ignore](https://crates.io/crates/ignore) library), but pypi doesn't really surface anything, half the packages are about creating ignorefiles, and the rest is either incomplete or abandoned.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```py
visible = filter(
    lambda path: not any((part for part in path.parts if part.startswith("."))),
    Path("my_path").rglob("*")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Great Question, there are two ways that I can think of that might help you depending on your use case. using os or pathlib.

```
from os import scandir
from pathlib import Path
# did shorthand for directory in directory
did = Path('path/to/parent/directory')
# with pathlib.Path()
paths = [dir_.as_posix() for dir_ in did.iterdir() if dir_.name[0]!='.']
# with os.scandir()
paths_ = [dir_.path for dir_ in scandir(did) if dir_.name[0]!='.']
paths_==paths
>>>True
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most simple option would be

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("/my/path")

[f for f in path.rglob('*') if not any([p for p in f.resolve().parts if p.startswith(".")])]
```

Note the `resolve` call to deal with relative paths as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use:

```
for p in path.rglob("*"):
    if p.is_dir() or p.name.startswith("."):
        continue
```